# Read a C file in java

Tags: java, c, parsing

I've looked for this issue on stack overflow but can't seem to find it.

How do I read a c file in my java program. I just want extracts all comments from an existing C file.

One method is to convert the c File into a txt file and use the following:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile ("example.txt", "rw");
```

However that ins't a scalable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many tutorials in the web how to read a file in java

Comment: A C source file is already a text file. It doesn't matter what the file extension is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the file, read it and after that parse lines with a little algorithm:

- All line start whit `'//'` is a comment.
- All char beetwin `'/*` and `'*/'` is a comment.

[Check that if you need to know how to read or write file in java :)](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html)

EDIT :

how it says in the comments there are other cases than these. The examples given by Broman and Holger are also to be handled :)

Comment: It's more complex than that. Consider `printf("/* This is not a comment */")`

Comment: i know it's more complex, but the question is not about algorithm but how to open file :) i just add a start for his algorithm.

Comment: But it is a terrible starting point. This way, you will end up adding rule over rule, to handle counter-examples and missing scenarios, until you realize, how much work you’ve wasted by not using a correct parser as a starting point. Even your first assumption is not correct, as a `//` comment doesn’t need to be at the start of a line. To expand @Broman’s example, `printf("// this is not a comment");` but `printf("");// this is a comment` and even worse, `printf("/* ");// be careful */ about the actual comment's ending\​` (Note the backslash at the line end)…

Comment: You just have to ignore all that is in quotation marks if you are not already in a comment and check after the semicolon if there is a comment. Other cases will cause a compilation error. Maybe I still make a mistake but for all classics cases it will work :) Sorry for my vagueness.

Comment: The semicolon is irrelevant. Comments can be everywhere, like `printf(/* comment */);` or `printf()// comment; there must be another semicolon in the next line`. And speaking of quotes, don’t forget, e.g. `"...\"..." ... // this is a comment "` and `"...\\"..." ... // but this not"`. I suppose, we can forgive not handling [digraphs and trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C)…

Comment: I hope I never have to read commented code like this haha